# How to trigger onMessage method on consumer with IBMMQ broker?

Tags: java, asynchronous, listener, ibm-mq, consumer

I try to read messages from IBM MQ.

This works when trying to do so by calling receive method on consumer.

However, when overriding onMessage method I get no messages and no errors. It seems like this method is never invoked.

Here is an example code which consumes messages from the queue correctly and prints them, but this method uses receive:

```
public class IBMMQConnect {

    private String hostName = "myHost";
    private int port = 1631;
    private String clientID = "clientID";
    private String channel = "channel";
    private int transportType = WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT;
    private String queueManager = "queueManager";
    private String sslCipherSuite = "sslCipherSuite";
    MQConnectionFactory mqConnectionFactory;
    CustomSslContectFactory sslFactory;
    javax.jms.ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    javax.jms.Connection connection;
    javax.jms.Session session;
    javax.jms.Topic topic;
    javax.jms.MessageConsumer consumer;
    public IBMMQConnect() throws Exception{
        System.setProperty("com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings", "false");
        this.mqConnectionFactory = new MQConnectionFactory();
        this.mqConnectionFactory.setHostName(hostName);
        this.mqConnectionFactory.setPort(port);
        this.mqConnectionFactory.setClientID(clientID);
        this.mqConnectionFactory.setChannel(channel);
        this.mqConnectionFactory.setTransportType(transportType);
        this.mqConnectionFactory.setQueueManager(queueManager);
        this.mqConnectionFactory.setSSLCipherSuite(sslCipherSuite);
        this.sslFactory = new CustomSslContextFactory();
        this.sslFactory.setKeyStore("myKeyStore");
        this.sslFactory.setKeyStorePassword("myPassword");
        this.sslFactory.setTrustStore("myTrustStore");
        this.sslFactory.setTrustStorePassword("password");
        this.mqConnectionFactory.setSSLSocketFactory(sslFactory.getSslContext().getSocketFactory());
        this.connectionFactory = this.mqConnectionFactory;
        this.connection = this.connectionFactory.createConnection();
        this.session = this.connection.createSession(false, javax.jms.Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        this.topic = this.session.createTopic("myTopic");
        this.consumer = this.session.createDurableSubscriber(topic, "myTest");
        javax.jms.Message message = null;
        this.connection.start();
        while ((message = consumer.receive(10*1000))!=null){
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    }

}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        IBMMQConnect ibmMQ = new IBMMQConnect();
    }
}
```

Now, here is an example where messages should be consumed by overriding method onMessage, however this code does not produce any output, it does not produce any errors, it looks like the consumer just never calls onMessage method:

```
public class IBMMQConnect {

    private String hostName = "myHost";
    private int port = 1631;
    private String clientID = "clientID";
    private String channel = "channel";
    private int transportType = WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT;
    private String queueManager = "queueManager";
    private String sslCipherSuite = "sslCipherSuite";
    MQConnectionFactory mqConnectionFactory;
    CustomSslContectFactory sslFactory;
    javax.jms.ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    javax.jms.Connection connection;
    javax.jms.Session session;
    javax.jms.Topic topic;
    javax.jms.MessageConsumer consumer;
    public IBMMQConnect() throws Exception{
        System.setProperty("com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings", "false");
        this.mqConnectionFactory = new MQConnectionFactory();
        this.mqConnectionFactory.setHostName(hostName);
        this.mqConnectionFactory.setPort(port);
        this.mqConnectionFactory.setClientID(clientID);
        this.mqConnectionFactory.setChannel(channel);
        this.mqConnectionFactory.setTransportType(transportType);
        this.mqConnectionFactory.setQueueManager(queueManager);
        this.mqConnectionFactory.setSSLCipherSuite(sslCipherSuite);
        this.sslFactory = new CustomSslContextFactory();
        this.sslFactory.setKeyStore("myKeyStore");
        this.sslFactory.setKeyStorePassword("myPassword");
        this.sslFactory.setTrustStore("myTrustStore");
        this.sslFactory.setTrustStorePassword("password");
        this.mqConnectionFactory.setSSLSocketFactory(sslFactory.getSslContext().getSocketFactory());
        this.connectionFactory = this.mqConnectionFactory;
        this.connection = this.connectionFactory.createConnection();
        this.session = this.connection.createSession(false, javax.jms.Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        this.topic = this.session.createTopic("myTopic");
        this.consumer = this.session.createDurableSubscriber(topic, "myTest");
        javax.jms.Message message = null;
        this.connection.start();
        this.consumer.setMessageListener(new MessageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMessage(Message message) {
                System.out.println(message);
            }
        });
        new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
    }

}
```

So, the first code example consumes messages and prints them, the second code example does not produce anything, no errors, no messages, why does it happen?

Comment: Usually these types of problems mean you haven't started the consumer.

Comment: it is not possible to start the consumer- it starts automatically when used with receive() method